# How to get rid of warnings when using Solve on an equation with inexact coefficients?

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages

When I solve this equation in Mathematica 8, I can get the right answer, but with some uncomfortable warnings.

Equation:

```
Solve[-26.81 == 194 k + k*l*32.9 && 22.2 == -74 k + k*l* 59.7, {k, l}]
```

Warnings:

> Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result. >>

If I transform the above equation to the following, then it works fine, but this is not convenient:

```
{k, kl/k} /. Solve[-26.81 == 194 k + kl*32.9 && 22.2 == -74 k + kl* 59.7, {k, kl}]
```

So my question is, how can I get rid of such warnings?

Comment: There's `Quiet[]`, but it's cheating in a certain sense...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can get rid of the warning by converting everything to exact numbers yourself before passing the equation to `Solve` (the warning message suggests that this is what `Solve` does itself):

```
In[2]:= Rationalize[-26.81 == 194 k + k*l*32.9 &&  22.2 == -74 k + k*l*59.7]
Out[2]= -(2681/100) == 194 k + (329 k l)/10 && 111/5 == -74 k + (597 k l)/10

In[3]:= Solve[%]
Out[3]= {{l -> -(2322860/2330937), k -> -(2330937/14016400)}}

In[4]:= N[%]
Out[4]= {{l -> -0.996535, k -> -0.166301}}
```

`Solve` (like all symbolic manipulation function) is meant to be used with exact numbers where roundoff errors are not an issue.  For solving the equation numerically, use `NSolve`:

```
In[5]:= NSolve[-26.81 == 194 k + k*l*32.9 && 22.2 == -74 k + k*l*59.7]
Out[5]= {{l -> -0.996535, k -> -0.166301}}
```

---

Some background on exact and inexact numbers:

- [Exact and Approximate Results](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ExactAndApproximateResults.html)
- In Mathematica, any number with a decimal point in it is considered to be inexact, i.e. known only to a certain number of digits. `2` is exact, `2.0` is inexact [machine precision](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MachinePrecisionNumbers.html) and `` 2.0`5 `` is inexact arbitrary precision [known to 5 digits](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NumericalPrecision.html).
- Symbolic computations (`Integrate`, `Solve`, `Reduce`, etc.) work best with exact numbers. Try to avoid inexact numbers with such functions.
- See more on [Numbers](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NumbersOverview.html)

Answer (score 11):

An alternative method would be to replace all inexact values with named parameters and replace afterwards, like this:

```
Solve[a == 194 k + k*l*b && c == -74 k + k*l*d, {k, l}]
```

> {{k -> (-b c + a d)/(74 b + 194 d), l -> (2 (37 a + 97 c))/(-b c + a d)}}

```
% /. {a -> -26.81, b -> 32.9, c -> 22.2, d -> 59.7}
```

> {{k -> -0.1663006906, l -> -0.9965348699}}

To automatize this process I introduce a function `inexactSolve` that, when placed against your complaining `Solve`, finds all inexact numbers, converts them to an inert function, solves the resulting equation and converts back.

```
ClearAll[inexactSolve]
SetAttributes[inexactSolve, HoldFirst]
inexactSolve[expr_Solve] := 
   ReleaseHold@ Replace[Hold[expr], a_?InexactNumberQ :> inert[ToString[a]], Infinity] 
     /. inert[a_String] :> ToExpression[a]
```

Demo:

```
inexactSolve@Solve[-26.81 == 194 k + k*l*32.9 && 22.2 == -74 k + k*l*59.7, {k, l}]
```

> {{k -> -0.1663006906, l -> -0.9965348699}}

How it works will be clear if I leave away the `/. inert[a_String] :> ToExpression[a]` part. The result then is:

[image: Mathematica graphics].

Of course, this may be considered as shooting sparrows with a cannon, but that can be very effective ;-)

Comment: May I propose: `inexactSolve[expr_Solve] := Block[{Identity},
  Unevaluated[expr] /. a_?InexactNumberQ :> Identity[a]
  ]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard That doesn't seem to work. It yields OP's original error message, at least on my system.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The closest I get when trying to work with your code is `inexactSolve[expr_Solve] := 
 ReleaseHold@
   Block[{Identity}, 
    Replace[Hold[expr], a_?InexactNumberQ :> Identity[ToString[a]], 
     Infinity]] /. Identity[a_String] :> ToExpression[a]`. Which means I get rid of `inert`. It seems that both the conversion to string and `Replace` with `Infinity` parameter are necessary.

Answer (score 9):

If you use `NSolve[]` instead of `Solve[]` (since indeed you are using inexact numbers like `26.81` in your equations), the warning you speak of should not show up.

Alternatively, you can wrap your `Solve[]` line in a `Quiet[]`, but that is not a strategy I can recommend in good conscience.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and using `NSolve` didn't work. I got similar message:

`NSolve::ratnz: NSolve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result`.

I found a solution here:

[Error/warning when using NSolve for simple equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24444/error-warning-when-using-nsolve-for-simple-equation)

It proposes using `Rationalize`

Comment: Rationalize was also used in the accepted answer on this page given by Szabolcs. You may have missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Simply solve as follows:

```
Solve[-26.81 == 194 k + k*l*32.9 && 22.2 == -74 k + k*l*59.7]
```

Result is:

```
{{l -> -0.996535, k -> -0.166301}}
```

No warning appears!

Comment: Warning appears with my MMA 11.0 (anyway, the warning has a reason, and this does not address this reason).

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure you don't want to ever see this warning message, you can always turn it off. First, using [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) with the message on:

```
Solve[-26.81==194 k+k*l*32.9&&22.2==-74 k+k*l*59.7,{k,l}]
```

> Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.
>
> {{k -> -0.166301, l -> -0.996535}}

Then, turn off the message and repeat:

```
Off[Solve::ratnz]
Solve[-26.81==194 k+k*l*32.9&&22.2==-74 k+k*l*59.7,{k,l}]
```

> {{k -> -0.166301, l -> -0.996535}}