# Handling "Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficient" errors

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get rid of warnings when using Solve on an equation with inexact coefficients?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6055/how-to-get-rid-of-warnings-when-using-solve-on-an-equation-with-inexact-coeffici)

I've been trying to calculate the following in *Mathematica*:

```
Solve[205.73/(1 + cet)^5 + 205.73/(1 + cet)^4 + 205.73/(1 + cet)^3 + 
    205.73/(1 + cet)^2 + 205.73/(1 + cet) == x, cet]
```

but it keeps returning

> "Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficient"

How can I calculate the above? I just want to isolate `cet` so I can create an algorithm to solve it.

Comment: I'd probably close this as a duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6055/5

Comment: I vote to close this. Read the linked post or try `expr = Rationalize[
   205.73/(1 + cet)^5 + 205.73/(1 + cet)^4 + 205.73/(1 + cet)^3 + 
         205.73/(1 + cet)^2 + 205.73/(1 + cet) == x];Solve[expr, cet]`

Comment: Btw, when you register here please feel welcome and don't take the close of your question personally. When you search this site (search box right on top) for "inexact coefficients" you come directly to the answer to your question. This, and reading the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/faq) should be the first thing to do before asking a question. Again, Welcome at Mathematica.SE.