# Error/warning when using NSolve for simple equation

Tags: equation-solving

I am using NSolve to solve an equation, as shown here:

```
T == (0.000250709 E^(0.0269867/(0.0000734429 + 1. T)))/(1.00025 - 
    1. E^(0.0539734/(0.0000734429 + 1. T)))

NSolve[T == (0.000250709 E^(0.0269867/(0.0000734429 + 
          1. T)))/(1.00025 - 
     1. E^(0.0539734/(0.0000734429 + 1. T))), {T}, Reals]
```

It gives me the warning `Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result. >>`, but still displays the result. Is it wrong to use NSolve for for such a general task, or am I missing a parameter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No errors if you work with exact arithmetic instead:

```
NSolve[Rationalize[
         T == (0.000250709 E^(0.0269867/(0.0000734429 + 1. T)))/
              (1.00025 - 1. E^(0.0539734/(0.0000734429 + 1. T))), 10^-10], {T}, Reals]

(*{{T -> -6.55871*10^-164}, {T -> 216.923}}*)
```

Comment: It works, thanks.. but I'm not sure why. Does `NSolve` have an issue working with high precision?

Comment: @niles, it's just that `NSolve[]` has some trouble if inexact numbers are present in the input. That's where `Rationalize[]` comes in.