# Solving problems with the floor function

Tags: equation-solving

I've got the following problem:

If I want to calculate the following equation,

```
S[EK_] = Floor[Piecewise[{{0, 0 < EK < 8130},
    {((933.70*((Floor[EK] - 8130)/10000) + 1400)*(Floor[EK] - 8130)/
        10000), 8130 < EK <= 
      13469}, {((228.74*((Floor[EK] - 13469)/10000) + 
          2397)*((Floor[EK] - 13469)/10000) + 1014), 
     13469 < EK <= 52881},
    {(0.42*Floor[EK] - 8196), 52881 < EK <= 250730},
    {(0.45*Floor[EK] - 15718), 250730 < EK}}]]

Solve[S[x]/x == 0.25, x]
```

*Mathematica* is calculating but cannot solve the equation. The same goes for another set of equations.

Does anybody see the error in the equation or the function?

Beste wishes

Comment: More or less a duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24444/131

Answer (score 6):

It is best to provide [exact numbers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18485/131) for `Solve`. This works (just a reminder, more often than not you should use `S[EK_]:=...` for function definitions, see e.g.: [What is the difference between Set and SetDelayed?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8829/131)):

```
Solve[S[x]/x == 0.25 // Rationalize, x]
```

> {{x -> 47876}, {x -> 47880}}