# Solving a trigonometric equation with one parameter

Tags: functions, infinite-loop

I have the following equation:

```
2 a^2 k^2 Sin[b k] - 6 a (k Cos[b k] - Sin[b k]/b) == 0
```

I set the value of `b` to 1, and I want to plot the value of `k` as it ranges over 0.01 to 6.0 in increments of 0.01.

When the above equation becomes zero for some value of `a`, I want to print the value of `k`. Later I will plot `k` as a function of ratio `a/b`.

This is a general question, but I am struggling with the logic can to solve this.

Do I put it in a loop?

```
xxx = 2 a^2 k^2 Sin[b k] - 6 a (k Cos[b k] - Sin[b k]/b)
b = 1;
Do[If[xxx == 0, {Print[k], Print[a]}, Continue[]], {a, 0.01, 6, 0.01}]
```

Thanks

Comment: Please have a look at `Table`, possibly together with `FindRoot` or `Solve`.

Answer (score 4):

Setting `b = 1` from the start, your equation can be rewritten as

```
(3 k)/(3 + a k^2) == Tan[k]
```

This has multiple solutions for `k` for any given value of `a`. Here's e.g. the plot of the LHS and the RHS for `a = 1`; the intersections are the solutions:

```
Plot[
 { (3 k)/(3 + k^2), Tan[k] }, 
 {k, -10, 10}, 
 Exclusions -> Tan[k] == 0, PlotPoints -> 500
]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Assuming you want the smallest solutions for `k > 0`, we can follow the logic from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54935/5485) by [Artes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/184/artes) and throw in [@Yves Klett](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/131/yves-klett)'s suggestion, to obtain

```
solutions = Table[
  {a, Min[ k /. NSolve[(3 k)/(3 + a k^2) == Tan[k] && 0 < k < 10, k] ]},
  {a, 1/100, 6, 1/100}
]

ListLinePlot[solutions]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that the range of `Table` is given in rationals rather than decimals; this is to [prevent `Solve` from giving warning messages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6055/5485).

Comment: I got this error: `Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result`, which I used `Quiet` to hide it. Should I be concerned about that?

Comment: @seismatica Good point, I forgot to mention that. No, you shouldn't: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6055/5485 . I've updated my answer; thanks for mentioning this!

Comment: Why call `Rationalize`? Why not `solutions =  Table[{N[a], Min[k /. NSolve[(3 k)/(3 + a k^2) == Tan[k] && 0 < k < 10, k]]}, {a, 1/100, 6, 1/100}]` instead?

Comment: @m_goldberg I agree, that's nicer -- I've updated the answer accordingly.